# Парсер файлов Битрикс

Tags: xml, битрикс

такой вопрос, есть 1с, которая формирует файл с товарами для битрикса, вот такого содержимого:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<КоммерческаяИнформация xmlns="urn:1C.ru:commerceml_2" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ВерсияСхемы="2.07" ДатаФормирования="2019-01-30T21:00:01">
    <Классификатор>
        <Ид>8563e659-c912-4ca9-b80d-2f420af1228e</Ид>
        <Наименование>Классификатор (Каталог товаров 1С)</Наименование>
        <Владелец>
            <Ид>2e964a32-787b-4a3a-8646-faa137cc3d07</Ид>
            <Наименование>ООО "Грин Лэнд"</Наименование>
            <ОфициальноеНаименование>Общество с ограниченной ответственностью "Грин Лэнд"</ОфициальноеНаименование>
            <ИНН>7805358539</ИНН>
            <КПП>781001001</КПП>
            <ОКПО/>
        </Владелец>
        <Группы>
            <Группа>
                <Ид>487ede7e-27a9-11e0-b9e1-003048337f61</Ид>
                <Наименование>  ГОРШКИ И КАШПО</Наименование>
                <Группы>
                    <Группа>
                        <Ид>487ede85-27a9-11e0-b9e1-003048337f61</Ид>
                        <Наименование>Пластик</Наименование>
                        <Группы>
                            <Группа>
                                <Ид>487edec6-27a9-11e0-b9e1-003048337f61</Ид>
                                <Наименование>3D пластик</Наименование>
                                <Группы>
                                    <Группа>
                                        <Ид>c6a8db92-636a-11e1-be65-003048337f61</Ид>
                                        <Наименование>Дизайн</Наименование>
                                    </Группа>
                                </Группы>
                            </Группа>
                        </Группы>
                    </Группа>
                </Группы>
            </Группа>
        </Группы>
        <Свойства>
            <Свойство>
                <Ид>645d3f22-cd1d-11e7-80c3-001e674943c0</Ид>
                <Наименование>Тег</Наименование>
                <ТипЗначений>Справочник</ТипЗначений>
                <ВариантыЗначений>
                    <Справочник>
                        <ИдЗначения>2ae61e34-cd2c-11e7-80c3-001e674943c0</ИдЗначения>
                        <Значение>интерьерные, комнатные, морозостойкие, напольные, для орхидеи, ударопрочные, уличные, высокие</Значение>
                    </Справочник>
                </ВариантыЗначений>
            </Свойство>
        </Свойства>
    </Классификатор>
    <Каталог СодержитТолькоИзменения="false">
        <Ид>8563e659-c912-4ca9-b80d-2f420af1228e</Ид>
        <ИдКлассификатора>8563e659-c912-4ca9-b80d-2f420af1228e</ИдКлассификатора>
        <Наименование>Каталог товаров 1С</Наименование>
        <Владелец>
            <Ид>2e964a32-787b-4a3a-8646-faa137cc3d07</Ид>
            <Наименование>ООО "Грин Лэнд"</Наименование>
            <ОфициальноеНаименование>Общество с ограниченной ответственностью "Грин Лэнд"</ОфициальноеНаименование>
            <ИНН>7805358539</ИНН>
            <КПП>781001001</КПП>
            <ОКПО/>
        </Владелец>
        <Товары>
            <Товар>
                <Ид>ef3ecca5-aa38-11e1-b991-003048337f61</Ид>
                <Артикул>21 453 070 037</Артикул>
                <Наименование>Брил Глосси конус d 30 h 68 см черный</Наименование>
                <БазоваяЕдиница Код="796 " НаименованиеПолное="Штука                                                                                               ">
                    <Пересчет>
                        <Единица>796</Единица>
                        <Коэффициент>1</Коэффициент>
                    </Пересчет>
                </БазоваяЕдиница>
                <Группы>
                    <Ид>c6a8db92-636a-11e1-be65-003048337f61</Ид>
                </Группы>
                <Описание/>
                <ЗначенияСвойств>
                    <ЗначенияСвойства>
                        <Ид>645d3f22-cd1d-11e7-80c3-001e674943c0</Ид>
                        <Значение>2ae61e34-cd2c-11e7-80c3-001e674943c0</Значение>
                    </ЗначенияСвойства>
                </ЗначенияСвойств>
                <СтавкиНалогов>
                    <СтавкаНалога>
                        <Наименование>НДС</Наименование>
                        <Ставка>20</Ставка>
                    </СтавкаНалога>
                </СтавкиНалогов>
                <ЗначенияРеквизитов>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>ВидНоменклатуры</Наименование>
                        <Значение>Товар (пр. ТМЦ) (б/х)</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>ТипНоменклатуры</Наименование>
                        <Значение>Товар</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                    <ЗначениеРеквизита>
                        <Наименование>Полное наименование</Наименование>
                        <Значение>Брил Глосси конус d 30 h 68 см черный</Значение>
                    </ЗначениеРеквизита>
                </ЗначенияРеквизитов>
            </Товар>
        </Товары>
    </Каталог>
</КоммерческаяИнформация>
```

Файл залетает в каталог Битрикса, после чего он им парсится и раскидывает сведения о товаре в базу.

Проблема вот в чем, хочу добавить в файл вес товара, почему-то сейчас данные о весе не записываются в файл. Гуру Битрикса, подскажите, куда нужно влепить данные о весе, чтобы они нормально потом распарсились? 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скриншоте показано куда должен попасть вес, это торговый каталог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот сюда:

```
<ЗначенияРеквизитов>
  ...
  <ЗначениеРеквизита>
    <Наименование>Вес</Наименование>
    <Значение>12</Значение>
  </ЗначениеРеквизита>
  ...
</ЗначенияРеквизитов>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это оно!